# NetworkPolicy has no effect on nginx-ingress namespace

Tags: security, kubernetes

I have used Rancher 2.2.8 to deploy a fresh Kubernetes cluster (v1.15.3) to a single fresh VM. I am trying to add a default 'deny all' NetworkPolicy to the Nginx ingress, to prevent any connections.

I apply the following to the `ingress-nginx` namespace:

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: http-deny-all
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  ingress: []
```

However, the site remains accessible.

I then create an 'nginx' daemonset in the `default` namespace, listening on host port 81. If I apply the same NetworkPolicy to the `default` namespace, it successfully blocks the traffic.

Why does the NetworkPolicy not apply for the `nginx-ingress` namespace? Is there something special about this namespace, or the `nginx-ingress-controller` daemonset that would prevent NetworkPolicy from working here?

Answer (score 1):

In the end, it turned out to be `hostNetwork: true` in the `nginx-ingress-controller` daemonset config. I removed this line, restarted the controller pods, and the NetworkPolicy now applies as expected.